# Hydrological triangle (geoscience) with QGIS 2.6.1

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I want to interpolate ( TIN-Interpolation) between variable points (the best within a triangle) WITHOUT producing new shapefiles (or csv data file).

So what I have now is an interpolation of all points but I want to choose between which point QGIS is interpolating. Normally, I need to load a new layer with new (3) points (within the x,y,z- variable) everytime.

How can I choose between certain points that QGIS should interpolate?